# python kernel crashes on mouse hover over Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, crash, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot graph in jupiter notebook.
When I use the following code

```
%pylab inline  
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,10,40)
plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.show()
```

everything works fine but if I change `%pylab inline` to `%pylab tk` or `%pylab qt` an interactive graph in separate window is shown and when I hover the mouse over the window python kernel crashes. Does anyone has idea how to solve this problem and plot graphs in separate windows?

I use Windows 7, Python 3.5.1 from Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit) distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want matplotlib interactive, i.e. the plots open in a separate window, you will want to execute the first cell of your notebook with the following magic:

```
%matplotlib
```

This should load an interactive backend for your system

If you want to work inline:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Then you can run your code, but please, do not use `pylab`, use `numpy` and `matplotlib.pyplot` instead; this will keep your namespaces tidy.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,40)
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.show()
```

To change back end during a session, you may have to restart your kernel in `jupyter` for the new backend settings to take effect.

Comment: Your solution displayes a window, but when I hover mouse over the window python crashes. So the problem is not yet solved. Probably something is wrong with my specific version of python/graphical backend.

Comment: I am afraid I can't help much further, I don't have a windows computer... Maybe you can look up the many matplotlib backends, and try to specify an alternative one? Maybe this one? http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_qt4agg_api.html